# Node js : works on local, but not on my server

Tags: node.js, hosting, connection-timeout, diagnostics

When trying node on my webserver (hosted by some company), i realized that it doesn't work.

The issue i get is a timeout error.

On my local machine, the script works. On the server, the script doesn't work, but i confirmed that node works, with a 'hello world' program.

Here, to perform my test on the webserver, i use the simplest node program i can think of (beside 'hello world') :

**Simple node program**

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 8080;

console.log("*** Node script launched ***");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log('Ok, server launched.');
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Message from the server : ok!');
});

server.listen(port,'0.0.0.0',function(){
  console.log((new Date())+' : OK. Server is listening.');
});
```

**Edit :** Corrected a typo in the program above. ==> Changed "Server.listen" into "server.listen". Thanks to @Num8er for noticing (unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue).

So after some research, i corrected one thing : specifying '0.0.0.0' as IP (before that, that part was left out). But it didn't solve my issue. And now, i can't find anything else that might be wrong (in the program. But i'm a newbie so...).

I suspect that the issue may come from my hoster, but i don't know how to pose a diagnostic on this situation.

Here is all the data i have :

**Program output when launched on the webserver**

```
*** Node script launched ***
Fri Aug 28 2015 01:45:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) : OK. Server is listening.
```

**Output from browser (chrome)**

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

I have 2 questions :

1. Do you have an idea what the problem might be?
2. Do you know the steps i could take to be able to pose a diagnostic on this situation. Is there a way to tell if node is correctly listening? Is there a way to monitor if my client request gets to the server. If yes, is it blocked? Where is it blocked?

Thanks.

Loïc.

Answer (score 1):

I think You're stopping application after You see the words:

> "OK. Server is listening."

Code works without problem.
I believe that You're closing terminal or doing ctrl+c
Try to run the app using forever.
Install it using:

```
npm install -g forever
```

run Your app using:

```
forever start app.js
```

stop it using:

```
forever stopall
```

check status:

```
forever list
```

There is one more thing also. 
If You using cloud services like C9. 
so better change port line to:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Comment: Hello Num8er. Thanks for the comment. It is a typo that i somehow introduced (i don't know how). When writing this post, i re-tested the program and noticed the "Server" instead of "server" (this caused an execution error). I had already copy-pasted and forgot to correct it in the post. But unfortunatley, it doesn't change the issue.

Comment: code is working fine, the question is how You navigate it in browser?

Comment: Hello num8er. I can assure you that i am not closing my terminal in any way. I also think that the code is fine (it is very simple after all). I really do suspect that the problem lies with the hoster, or server configuration, or something along those lines. I tried checking what ports are open on the server, but i don't seem to have the rights for that : `netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
netstat: /proc/net/tcp: Permission denied
netstat: /proc/net/tcp6: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

Also, not sure about the webserver you're using, but the Port # might also be an issue.

I do know that on Heroku deployments I have to use something along the lines of:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your application is fine but your port `8080` is not open in you server , Have you tried to navigate to `http://serverip:8080` if it has `ERR_TIMED_OUT` problem , then the problem is in your port as I said.